# New Relic Insight - Combined Chart

Tags: newrelic, nrql

I've recently started implementing New Relic to get a better overview of my application, and have found Insight, which seems to be really cool.

What I'm trying to achieve now is to create one chart that relays the same info from several servers.

Example: I want a "CPU load" load with four graph lines; for servers DB01, DB02, Web01 and Web02 respectively, but I have only been able to create NRQL for Transactions; not metrics.

Is is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

New Relic Server Monitor data is not collected in NRDB (the database that supports Insights) so it is not possible to perform queries or create charts using Insights.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to create this using legacy charts, or otherwise achieve this functionality?